# Ctrl-C interrupts process, but doesn't clear terminal line

Tags: zsh, shortcut-keys, interrupts

When I press `Ctrl-C`, I receive interrupts for running processes (e.g., `sleep 10`, followed by `Ctrl-C`, will immediately terminate the running process). However, it doesn't clear the terminal line - in fact, pretty much nothing works.

I've tried to reset my keybindings using `stty sane`, I've also checked out my keybinding for `tmux` (although, I have the same problem even when I run `zsh` without tmux). I can't find any problems with the bindings, and I'm out of ideas!

Are there any other ways to debug or test out what could be causing the issue?

Comment: I want `zsh` to have ctrl-c not clear the line after recalling a previous command with ctrl-r. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a mystery `trap INT ...` in my `.zshrc`. As soon as I removed that, `Ctrl-C` worked as expected again, clearing and returning.

I guess that this `trap` command swallowed my `Ctrl-C`, and therefore it didn't cancel the input!